# press multiple buttons and save it in a chronic for further action

Tags: c#

first of all, c# is new for me. let me apologize in advance for this newbie question.

at the moment i am working on an elevator gui (windows forms in visual studio 2017). 
if i press a button on a random floor and wait until the elevator reaches its destination, and then press another button, the code seems to work. now i would like to integrate the possibility, that the buttons on the floor can be pressed almost at the same time, one after another.
e.g. press button level floor 2, press button level floor 0, press button level floor 1. the elevator should then go to floor 2, then to floor 0 and finally reach floor 1 (voyager commands are yet excluded).

i tried to store these calls in a list, to let the elevator working off that list. unfortunately, when i push the buttons randomely, the code doesn't work anymore. i guess the mistake is, that it always reruns the Move() function after every pressed button.

how can i save the order of these pressed buttons, so the programm can proceed an other action with this information?
thx for any answers.

Code Snippet:

```
    int elevatorposition = 2;
    List<int> Queue = new List<int>();

    private void btnCall0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //floor 0
    {
        Call(0);
        Move();
    }

    private void btnCall1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //floor 1
    {
        Call(1);
        Move();
    }

    private void btnCall2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    //floor 2
    {
        Call(2);
        Move();
    }

    private new async void Move()
    {
        await h();
    }

    private async Task h()
    {
        if (Queue.Contains(0) || Queue.Contains(1) || Queue.Contains(2))
        {
           int callerposition = Queue[0];

           if (callerposition < elevatorposition)
            {
               while (callerposition < elevatorposition)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    elevatorposition--;
                    LabelElevatorPosition(elevatorposition);
                }
            Queue.RemoveAt(0);
            }

           else if (callerposition > elevatorposition)
            {
               while (callerposition > elevatorposition)
                {
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                elevatorposition++;
                LabelElevatorPosition(elevatorposition);
                }
            Queue.RemoveAt(0);
            }   
        }
    }

    private void Call(int x)
    {
        Queue.Add(x);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try just 2 in a row? I guess you should stuck to your click handler since there are async method calls from not async context.